# RED5 Server, build and modify oflaDemo, version issue

Tags: java, eclipse, rtmp, red5

I am trying to update and debug the RED5 oflaDemo application, using Eclipse I have imported the RED5 plugin.  When I try and debug oflaDemo on server, the RED5 server starts but there are some errors which seem to have been attributed to Java version mismatch.  I have tried multiple with no avail:

- RED5 v1.0.4, Java JDK 1.6
- RED5 v1.0.5, Java JDK 1.8

I always get:

```
***[INFO] [Launcher:/] org.red5.server.scope.Scope - Invalid scope name, null is not allowed
[WARN] [Launcher:/] org.red5.server.scope.Scope - Invalid scope rejected: Scope [name=null, path=/default, type=APPLICATION, autoStart=true, creationTime=1426471784657, depth=1, enabled=true, running=false]
[WARN] [Launcher:/] org.red5.server.scope.Scope - Scope not added to parent
[INFO] [Launcher:/] org.red5.server.scope.WebScope - Webscope already registered***
```

I do NOT have 2 `RED5.jar` files - anyone else had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on centos 7 that might be the issue cause I can;t get it to work on centos 7?

Comment: on stock centos 7.1, use red5 version 1.0.4-RELEASE and jdk 1.7 (jdk-7u79). works like a charm. 1.0.5 needs java 8.

Answer (score 0):

That's the "ROOT" web application; don't mind it since it won't negatively affect your red5 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use red5 1.0.4 with jdk 1.7 (jdk-7u79). Nothing else needed. Make sure to use Oracle JDK (to download on the server-side, use `wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-linux-x64.tar.gz"`).